# Simple way of excluding an element from a calculation on a list?

Tags: python, list

For example I want to check the correlation coefficient between two lists like:

```
r = np.corrcoef(list25, list26)[0,1]
```

but I want to exclude -1's in the lists from the calculation. Is there a simple one-liner way of doing this instead of making a new copies of the lists and iterating through to remove all -1's and such?

Comment: You want to filter the lists? `filter(lambda x: x != -1, values)`

Comment: Or a list comprehension: `[x for x in mylist if x != -1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a one liner solution. It's creating a new list without the ones. It can be done using [List Comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if x != -1]
```

it basically copies everything that matches the condition from the old list to the new list.

So, for your example:

```
r = np.corrcoef([x for x in list25 if x != -1], [x for x in list26 if x != -1])[0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator

```
def greater_neg_1(items):
    for item in items:
        if item>-1:
            yield item
```

Usage:

```
>>> L = [1,-1,2,3,4,-1,4]
>>> list(greater_neg_1(L))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

or:

```
r = np.corrcoef(greater_neg_1(list25), greater_neg_1(list26))[0,1]
```

Won't require any extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to remove the `-1` from the lists:

```
while -1 in list25: list25.remove(-1)
```